# how to select value from "storage integration" in snowflake?

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have created storage integration by executing below command

```
create or replace storage integration stager 
       type = external_stage
       storage_provider = s3
       enabled = true
       storage_aws_role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::24545426:role/test'
       storage_allowed_locations = ('s3://testb/')
```

after that I have executed `DESC INTEGRATION stager`

i got the result like

[image]

now I want select `STORAGE_AWS_EXTERNAL_ID` and `property value` of the `stager` .

how to select  `STORAGE_AWS_EXTERNAL_ID` and `property value`  using query or python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RESULT_SCAN function to process the outcome of another query (using SQL):

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html#examples-using-describe-and-show-commands

For python:

```
import snowflake.connector

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
      ...
) 


cs = ctx.cursor()

try:
    sql = "DESC INTEGRATION stager"
    cs.execute( sql )
    for (c_property, c_type, c_value, c_default) in cs:
        if c_property == "STORAGE_AWS_EXTERNAL_ID":
            print('{0}, {1}'.format(c_property, c_value))


finally:
    cs.close()
```

This is the result of the above Python script:

```
STORAGE_AWS_EXTERNAL_ID, WX65722_SFCRole=2_GpY+ZF0b41Nu3d2ZDFYPfCUbBxk=
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply, after executing above  i am getting "property
property_value
property
property_value
property
property_value
property
property_value
property
property_value
property
property_value
property
property_value
"

Comment: it is not going inside if

Comment: values not printing only column headers we are getting

Comment: sai, let me share the whole script - I use snowflake.connector package